# How does one use Django custom management command option?

Tags: django, django-manage.py

The Django doc tell me how to add an option to my django custom management command, via an example:

```
from optparse import make_option

class Command(BaseCommand):
    option_list = BaseCommand.option_list + (
        make_option('--delete',
            action='store_true',
            dest='delete',
            default=False,
            help='Delete poll instead of closing it'),
    )
```

Then the docs just stop. How would one write the `handle` method for this class to check whether the user has supplied a `--delete` option? At times Django makes the easy things difficult :-(

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
from optparse import make_option

class Command(BaseCommand):
    option_list = BaseCommand.option_list + (
        make_option('--del',
            action='store_true',
            help='Delete poll'),
        make_option('--close',
            action='store_true',
            help='Close poll'),
    )

    def handle(self, close, *args, **kwargs):
        del_ = kwargs.get('del')
```

Do note that some keywords in Python are reserved so you can handle those using `**kwargs`. Otherwise you can use normal arguments (like I did with `close`)

Comment: The reserved word is `del`. `delete` is permitted as a variable name.

Comment: For others coming to this thread, this resource helped me out too : http://www.alexonlinux.com/pythons-optparse-for-human-beings#telling_optparse_to_parse_arguments

Answer (score 7):

A little suggestion about defining the commands (key name, `dest`) and handling default values (in `make_option` and in the command):

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    option_list = BaseCommand.option_list + (
        make_option('--del',
            action='store_true',
            help='Delete all polls.',
            dest='your_name_for_delete',
            default=False),
        make_option('--close',
            action='store_true',
            help='Close all polls.'),
    )

    def handle(self, close, *args, **options):
        if options.get('your_name_for_delete'):
            Poll.objects.delete()
        if options.get('close', False):
            Poll.objects.update(closed=True)
```

In Django code you'll find "keyword arguments" (`**kwargs`) often named as `**options`, which is more suggestive (I stick to this naming convention).

The default value can be either specified in make_option, or through the `dict.get` method,
which allows for a default value.

There's no reason not u use **both** defaults, should your `Command.handle` method be called manually, where the `**options` dictionary could be missing this entry.