# Writing a custom management command with args and options - explanation of fields needed

Tags: django, command

In my django app I am writing a custom management command which will create an instance of an object based on the args passed and have the option of saving it to the database based on whether an option `--save` is passed or not.

I've got a lot of help on this from the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-management-commands/) itself. Have also got important pointers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568864/two-arguments-in-django-admin-custom-command) about how to pass multiple arguments and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208006/how-does-one-use-django-custom-management-command-option) about how to have options.

```
from optparse import make_option

class Command(BaseCommand):
  option_list = BaseCommand.option_list + (
    make_option('--delete',
        action='store_true',
        dest='delete',
        default=False,
        help='Delete poll instead of closing it'),
    )

  def handle(self, *args, **options):
    # ...
    if options['delete']:
        poll.delete()
    # ...
```

However I am not able to find a detailed explanation of the fields in make_option. For example [optparse.make_option](http://nullege.com/codes/search/optparse.make_option) lists

```
Instance attributes:
_short_opts : [string]
_long_opts : [string]

action : string
type : string
dest : string
default : any
nargs : int
const : any
choices : [string]
callback : function
callback_args : (any*)
callback_kwargs : { string : any }
help : string
metavar : string
```

In this `help` is self explanatory and I figured out what `dest` would mean, but I'm not clear what `action='store_true'` means. In fact it'd be great if someone could give me a short description of what all the arguments to `make_option` mean...

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[The optparse docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html#defining-options) might be a little bit more helpful. You are basically telling the management function what each option you require should do.

The [`action`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html#optparse-standard-option-actions) keyword is the most telling and it configures what you want to do with that option - is it just a flag to do something special (a `callback`, i.e. '--enable-feature') or should it accept a parameter for example (`store`, i.e. '-things 10').

With that in mind, the rest of the options make a bit more sense with that all in mind. Read through ['option attributes'](http://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html#option-attributes) to get an explanation of what you've listed, and then ['actions'](http://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html#standard-option-actions) to see what I've mentioned above

Answer (score 34):

### Explanation of make_option from the docs http://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html#populating-the-parser

> make_option() is a factory function for creating Option instances;
> currently it is an alias for the Option constructor. A future version
> of optparse may split Option into several classes, and make_option()
> will pick the right class to instantiate. Do not instantiate Option
> directly.

### These are all of the possible option attributes:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html#option-attributes

### Common Use in a django management command:

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = "Command to import a list of X"
    option_list = BaseCommand.option_list + (
        make_option(
            "-f", 
            "--file", 
            dest = "filename",
            help = "specify import file", 
            metavar = "FILE"
        ),
    )

    option_list = option_list + (
        make_option(
            "-s", 
            "--slug", 
            dest = "category",
            help = "category slug", 
            metavar = "SLUG"
        ),
    )

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
            # make sure file option is present
            if options['filename'] == None :
                raise CommandError("Option `--file=...` must be specified.")
        
            # make sure file path resolves
            if not os.path.isfile(options['filename']) :
                raise CommandError("File does not exist at the specified path.")
    
            # make sure form option is present
            if options['category'] == None :
                raise CommandError("Option `--slug=...` must be specified.")
```

Comment: This is not applicable in Django 1.8 as it is deprecated. Please find more information at this page: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-management-commands/